# Google App Engine(java) - App upload failed due to app size limit exceeded - (free account)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, quota, application-size

i am using **Google app engine** for my development, my project involves **around 60 PDfs** to be available for users to download.

when i try to **upload** the project by clicking **deploy** button in **eclipse** i get the error **app limit exceeded**.

i just want to know if i try to use the paid account is there is a different in the application  size in paid account or not?

as far as i know its **150 MB** for now

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Blobstore service](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) to store your PDF files and keep application only for files needed by your application logic and presentation, not data. Here is description of the Blobstore:

> The Blobstore API allows your app to serve data objects, called blobs,
>   that are much larger than the size allowed for objects in the
>   Datastore service. Blobs are created by uploading a file through an
>   HTTP request. Typically, your apps will do this by presenting a form
>   with a file upload field to the user. When the form is submitted, the
>   Blobstore creates a blob from the file's contents and returns an
>   opaque reference to the blob, called a blob key, which you can later
>   use to serve the blob.

Comment: This is the way to go. Build your app with an upload capability (which you can restrict to admin users of your app (e.g., you)), then load the PDFs after you deploy your app. This has the secondary benefit of leaving the PDFs in place if/when you upgrade your app.

Answer (score 1):

All good advice above, try to avoid putting content like that in your code. My app hit this issue and only has about 10MB of code/images/resources. What takes up a lot of space is the GWT compiling of 15 permutations of your app.

One thing that helped me, was changing my GWT javascript generation output style from Details to Obfuscated, resulting in much smaller code. You can also limit the number of permutations being created.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling#Can_I_speed_up_the_GWT_compiler?

Answer (score 0):

upto 10MB data u can upload to ur app engine 
see following link

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html

Comment: Yes 1 GB in the data store (DB), but upload app size itself is said to be limited to 10 MB.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://code.google.com/intl/de/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Deployments the applications may not exceed 10 MB.